# Loop slowdown using Python instead of shell script

Tags: python, shell, loops, memory, slowdown

I have two Python scripts `network.py` and `analysis.py`, where the first one reads in a timeseries as `np.array` (about 180mb), trains a neural network on it using some `parameters`, creates `predictions` and saves it as `.txt` file along with `truth` for possible later inspection (both files up to about 160mb). These files are then read in by the second script, which generates values that are stored in a multidimensional `np.array`, the dimensionality depending on the number of previously mentioned`parameters`. These were previously passed in via shell script as arguments using `sys`.

I wanted to retrieve values over the whole parameter space and used a shell script loop for that. I let it run overnight and didnt measure the time it took, but one can estimate it to run about 12 hours.

In order to make that faster, I did the following: Instead of a shell script, I used another python script, importing the necessary functionality of `network.py` and `analysis.py`, looping over them. I passed `truth` and `predictions` from one script to another without saving and reading and got rid of having to read in the timeseries (mentioned at the very beginning) at every loop.

I let it run overnight again and having a look after about 20 hours, it had only finished about 65%, progressing really slow, much much slower than at the beginning of the run. Using `top` I saw that the process occupied about 26g of virtual memory, which seems insanely much to me.

Did I miss something very basic? Is there a common mistake? I couldnt find an answer yet. Your help is highly appreciated!

Here are the full scripts.
Im sorry they are a bit messy, its all work in progress...

The loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from kerasNetwork import network
from analysis import analysis

thesis_home = '/home/r/Raphael.Kriegmair/uni/master/thesis'
n = 1
size = '10000'
print("INFO: Reading training data")
inputStates = np.loadtxt(thesis_home + '/trainingData/modifiedShallowWater/mswOutput_' + size + '.txt')
for variables in 'u', 'h', 'r', 'uh', 'ur', 'hr', 'uhr':
    for hiddenLayers in '1', '2', '3', '4', '5':
        for nodesPerLayer in '50', '100', '250', '500', '750':
            for train in '0.1', '0.3', '0.5', '0.7', '0.9':
                truth, predictions = network(inputStates, size, variables, hiddenLayers, nodesPerLayer, train)
                analysis(truth, predictions, size, variables, hiddenLayers, nodesPerLayer,train)
                print('CURRENTLY:  ' + str(n) + ' / 875' )
                n = n+1
```

`network.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D#, Activation, BatchNormalization
#from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import numpy as np


def network(inputStates, size, variables, hiddenLayers, nodesPerLayer, train):

    nodesPerLayer = int(nodesPerLayer)
    train = float(train)    

    print("INFO: Preprocessing training data")
    # input/output state pairs share time index
    outputStates = inputStates[:, 1:]
    inputStates = inputStates[:, :-1]


    # split variables

    u_input = inputStates[0:250,:]
    h_input = inputStates[250:500,:]
    r_input = inputStates[500:750,:]

    u_output = outputStates[0:250,:]
    h_output = outputStates[250:500,:]
    r_output = outputStates[500:750,:]

    numStates = len(inputStates[0,:])


    # normalize data

    u_mean = np.mean(u_input)
    h_mean = np.mean(h_input)
    r_mean = np.mean(r_input)

    u_sigma = np.std(u_input)
    h_sigma = np.std(h_input)
    r_sigma = np.std(r_input)

    u_input, u_output = (u_input - u_mean)/u_sigma, (u_output - u_mean)/u_sigma
    h_input, h_output = (h_input - h_mean)/h_sigma, (h_output - h_mean)/h_sigma
    r_input, r_output = (r_input - r_mean)/r_sigma, (r_output - r_mean)/r_sigma


    # choose variables

    if variables == 'uhr':
        trainInput = np.concatenate((u_input,
                                     h_input,
                                     r_input,
                                     ), axis = 0)
        trainOutput = np.concatenate((u_output,
                                      h_output,
                                      r_output
                                      ), axis = 0)

    elif variables == 'uh':
        trainInput = np.concatenate((u_input,
                                     h_input
                                     ), axis = 0)
        trainOutput = np.concatenate((u_output,
                                      h_output
                                      ), axis = 0)

    elif variables == 'ur':
        trainInput = np.concatenate((u_input,
                                     r_input
                                     ), axis = 0)
        trainOutput = np.concatenate((u_output,
                                      r_output
                                      ), axis = 0)

    elif variables == 'hr':
        trainInput = np.concatenate((h_input,
                                     r_input
                                     ), axis = 0)
        trainOutput = np.concatenate((h_output,
                                      r_output
                                      ), axis = 0)


    elif variables == 'u':
        trainInput = u_input
        trainOutput = u_output

    elif variables == 'h':
        trainInput = h_input
        trainOutput = h_output

    elif variables == 'r':
        trainInput = r_input
        trainOutput = r_output

    else:
        print('ARGUMENT ERROR: INVALID VARIABLE COMBINATION')

    dim = len(trainInput[:,0])


    print("INFO: Initializing model")
    # activations: relu, sigmoid, ...
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(nodesPerLayer, activation='relu', input_dim=dim))
    #BatchNormalization()

    for layers in range(int(hiddenLayers)-1):
        model.add(Dense(nodesPerLayer, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(dim, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])



    # Train the model, iterating on the data 
    print("INFO: Training")

    val = 1 - train
    model.fit(np.swapaxes(trainInput,0,1), np.swapaxes(trainOutput,0,1), epochs=15, validation_split=val)



    print("INFO: Generating predictions")
    # generate predictions

    predictionNumStates = int(numStates*val)
    trainNumStates = int(numStates*train)
    predictions = np.empty((1,) + trainInput[:,:predictionNumStates].shape)
    print("Predictions shape:  ", predictions.shape)

    predictions[0,:,:] = trainInput[:,trainNumStates+1:]

    for n in range(predictionNumStates-1):
        #print(predictions[:,n].shape)
        #, steps=1
        # TODO: why do I need this extra index here???
        predictions[:,:,n] = model.predict(predictions[:,:,n])


    print("INFO: Saving results")
    # compare
    truth = trainOutput[:,trainNumStates+1:]
    predictions = predictions[0,:,:]
    #difference = np.square(truth - predictions[0,:,:])

    return truth, predictions

#    predictions_filename = 'predictions_' + size + '_' + variables + '_' + hiddenLayers + '_' + str(nodesPerLayer) + '_' + str(train) + '.txt'
#    truth_filename = 'truth_' + size + '_' + variables + '_' + str(train) + '.txt'
#    
#    # these files are moved to "work" directory afterwards by experiments' shell script
#    np.savetxt(thesis_home + '/temporary/' + predictions_filename, predictions)
#    np.savetxt(thesis_home + '/temporary/' + truth_filename, truth)
```

`analysis.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import sys 

#expPath = sys.argv[1]
#size = sys.argv[2]
#variables = sys.argv[3]
#hiddenLayers = sys.argv[4]
#train = sys.argv[5]
#nodesPerLayer = sys.argv[6]


#predictions_filename = 'predictions_' + size + '_' + variables + '_' + hiddenLayers + '_' + str(nodesPerLayer) + '_' + str(train) + '.txt'
#truth_filename = 'truth_' + size + '_' + variables + '_' + str(train) + '.txt'
#
#predictions = np.loadtxt(thesis_home + '/temporary/' + predictions_filename)
#truth = np.loadtxt(thesis_home + '/temporary/' + truth_filename)


def analysis(truth, predictions, size, variables, hiddenLayers, nodesPerLayer,train):

    print('INFO: Analysis part')

    thesis_home = '/home/r/Raphael.Kriegmair/uni/master/thesis'

    index_size = {0 : 10000}
    index_nodesPerLayer = {0 : 50, 1 : 100, 2 : 250, 3 : 500, 4 : 750}
    index_train = {0 : 0.1, 1 : 0.3, 2 : 0.5, 3 : 0.7, 4 : 0.9}
    index_hiddenLayers = {0 : 1, 1 : 2, 2 : 3, 3 : 4, 4 : 5}
#    index_variables = {0 : 'u', 1 : 'h', 2 : 'r', # single
#                       3 : 'u', 4 : 'h', # pair
#                       5 : 'u', 6 : 'r', # pair
#                       7 : 'h', 8 : 'r', # pair
#                       9 : 'u', 10 : 'h', 11 : 'r'} # combined

    size_index = {v:k for k,v in index_size.items()}
    nodesPerLayer_index = {v:k for k,v in index_nodesPerLayer.items()}
    train_index = {v:k for k,v in index_train.items()}
    hiddenLayers_index = {v:k for k,v in index_hiddenLayers.items()}
    #variables_index = {v:k for k,v in index_variables.items()}
    # 12 is trash key
    variable_keys = {'u': (0,12,12),
                     'h': (12,1,12),
                     'r': (12,12,2),
                     'uh': (3,4,12),
                     'ur': (5,12,6),
                     'hr': (12,7,8),
                     'uhr': (9,10,11)}



    difference = np.square(truth - predictions)
    # from now on only absolute value of truth needed
    truth = np.absolute(truth)


    timesteps = len(difference[0,:])


    if variables == 'uhr':   

        u_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        h_mean = np.mean(truth[250:500,:])
        r_mean = np.mean(truth[500:750,:])

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / u_mean
        h_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[250:500,:], axis=0)) / h_mean
        r_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[500:750,:], axis=0)) / r_mean


    elif variables == 'uh':

        u_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        h_mean = np.mean(truth[250:500,:])
        r_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / u_mean
        h_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[250:500,:], axis=0)) / h_mean
        r_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))

    elif variables == 'ur':

        u_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        h_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_mean = np.mean(truth[250:500,:])

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / u_mean
        h_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[250:500,:], axis=0)) / r_mean

    elif variables == 'hr':

        u_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        r_mean = np.mean(truth[250:500,:])

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / h_mean
        r_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[250:500,:], axis=0)) / r_mean

    elif variables == 'u':

        u_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        h_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / u_mean
        h_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))

    elif variables == 'h':    

        u_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])
        r_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / h_mean
        r_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))

    elif variables == 'r':

        u_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_mean = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_mean = np.mean(truth[:250,:])

        # relative error
        u_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        h_rmse = np.zeros((timesteps))
        r_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(difference[:250,:], axis=0)) / r_mean



    # compute running mean

    u_runningMean = np.zeros((timesteps))
    h_runningMean = np.zeros((timesteps))
    r_runningMean = np.zeros((timesteps))

    usum_ = 0.
    hsum_ = 0.
    rsum_ = 0.
    for i in range(timesteps):
        usum_ += u_rmse[i]
        hsum_ += h_rmse[i]
        rsum_ += r_rmse[i]
        u_runningMean[i] = usum_/(i+1)
        h_runningMean[i] = hsum_/(i+1)
        r_runningMean[i] = rsum_/(i+1)



    # compute running standard deviation

    u_runningStdDev = np.zeros((timesteps))
    h_runningStdDev = np.zeros((timesteps))
    r_runningStdDev = np.zeros((timesteps))

    usum_ = 0.
    hsum_ = 0.
    rsum_ = 0.
    for i in range(timesteps):
        usum_ += np.square(u_rmse[i] - u_runningMean[i])
        hsum_ += np.square(h_rmse[i] - h_runningMean[i])
        rsum_ += np.square(r_rmse[i] - r_runningMean[i])
        u_runningStdDev[i] = np.sqrt(usum_/(i+1))
        h_runningStdDev[i] = np.sqrt(hsum_/(i+1))
        r_runningStdDev[i] = np.sqrt(rsum_/(i+1))



    # dirty fix for suspiciously large last values   
    u_rmse[timesteps-1] = u_runningMean[timesteps-1]
    h_rmse[timesteps-1] = h_runningMean[timesteps-1]
    r_rmse[timesteps-1] = r_runningMean[timesteps-1]



    #results = np.zeros((12, # 3 single = 3, 3 pairs = 6, 1 combined = 3
    #                    len(size_index),
    #                    len(nodesPerLayer_index),
    #                    len(train_index),
    #                    len(hiddenLayers_index)))

    results = np.load(thesis_home + '/experiments/results.npy')

    u_index = variable_keys[variables][0]
    h_index = variable_keys[variables][1]
    r_index = variable_keys[variables][2]

    results[u_index, 
            size_index[int(size)], nodesPerLayer_index[int(nodesPerLayer)], train_index[float(train)], hiddenLayers_index[int(hiddenLayers)]] = u_runningMean[timesteps-1]

    results[h_index, 
            size_index[int(size)], nodesPerLayer_index[int(nodesPerLayer)], train_index[float(train)], hiddenLayers_index[int(hiddenLayers)]] = h_runningMean[timesteps-1]

    results[r_index, 
            size_index[int(size)], nodesPerLayer_index[int(nodesPerLayer)], train_index[float(train)], hiddenLayers_index[int(hiddenLayers)]] = r_runningMean[timesteps-1]

    np.save(thesis_home + '/experiments/results.npy', results)
```

Comment: Without code or some indication of the size of the objects that you are creating/using makes it hard to comment.

Comment: I added some info about sizes of timeseries, prediction and truth. Getting together the relevant pieces of code.